# How to make a 2D char* array with NULL(s) in C with a struct || error: expected expression before '{' token

Tags: c, hashtable

I want to make a hashtable in c, where the keys are integers and the values are strings

I have a 2D char array in a struct, as follows in hashtable.h file:

```
#ifndef hashtable
#define hashtable

// define the maxmium size
#define INITIAL_SIZE 5
#define LOAD_FACTOR 0.7

typedef struct hashtable
{
    int* keyArray[INITIAL_SIZE]; 
    char* valueArray[INITIAL_SIZE][101]; // strings have maximum of 100 chars
    bool isActiveArray[INITIAL_SIZE]; // for deleting elements

    int count;
    int capacity;
    double loadFactor;

    // true: linear probing, false: quadratic probing
    bool collisionHandler;

} table;

#endif
```

I am trying to initialize the values of the arrays outside of the struct, like so

```
void initTable(table* p) {
    // constructor
    p->count = 0;
    p->capacity = INITIAL_SIZE;
    p->loadFactor = LOAD_FACTOR; 
    p->collisionHandler = true;
    p->keyArray = {NULL};
    p->valueArray = {{NULL}};
    p->isActiveArray = {false};
}
```

however i receive these errors:

```
In file included from HashTable.c:22:0:
functions.h: In function 'initTable':
functions.h:85:16: error: expected expression before '{' token
  p->keyArray = {NULL};
                ^
functions.h:86:18: error: expected expression before '{' token
  p->valueArray = {{NULL}};
                  ^
functions.h:87:21: error: expected expression before '{' token
  p->isActiveArray = {false};
```

note: p is a pointer to my table struct

I want to know how to make a 2D array of all NULL values in the char* array, like
`{{NULL}, {NULL}, {NULL}}` also to use for comparison later on like trying to insert a value into the valueArray, and checking if null

I also want to make the keyArray, the int* list to be like {NULL, NULL, NULL} instead of a random memory address so I can easily check for a NULL pointer, and then replace it with a pointer to an int when making a new key/value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing the values of an array using the `{` `}` brace syntax will only work in a declaration. You cannot use that syntax after an array has already been declared.

If you really want to use the brace syntax after an array has already been declared, one thing you can do is declare another temporary array of the same type and size and initialize it with the brace syntax, and then copy the temporary array to the original array using [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy), for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    //declare array without initializing it
    int arr[5];

    //create temporary array and initialize it with brace syntax
    const int temp[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    //copy temporary array to original array
    memcpy( arr, temp, sizeof arr );

    //print contents of original array
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", arr[i] );
    }
}
```

This program will output the numbers `1` to `5`.

Using this method, your function `initTable` would look like this:

```
void initTable( table* p ) {
    // constructor
    p->count = 0;
    p->capacity = INITIAL_SIZE;
    p->loadFactor = LOAD_FACTOR;
    p->collisionHandler = true;

    const int* temp_keyArray[INITIAL_SIZE] = { NULL };
    memcpy( p->keyArray, temp_keyArray, sizeof temp_keyArray );

    const char* temp_valueArray[INITIAL_SIZE][101] = { NULL };
    memcpy( p->valueArray, temp_valueArray, sizeof temp_valueArray );

    const bool temp_isActiveArray[INITIAL_SIZE] = { false };
    memcpy( p->isActiveArray, temp_isActiveArray, sizeof temp_isActiveArray );
}
```

However, since you want to initialize all array elements to zero, there is a simpler solution. You can use the function [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) to set all bytes of the array to zero:

```
void initTable( table* p ) {
    // constructor
    p->count = 0;
    p->capacity = INITIAL_SIZE;
    p->loadFactor = LOAD_FACTOR;
    p->collisionHandler = true;
    memset( p->keyArray, 0, sizeof p->keyArray );
    memset( p->valueArray, 0, sizeof p->valueArray );
    memset( p->isActiveArray, 0, sizeof p->isActiveArray );
}
```

Or, as already pointed out in the other answer by someone else, you can set all bytes of the entire `struct hashtable` to zero using `memset` and afterwards only set the values of the individual members of the `struct` which are not supposed to be zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, in your use of memset I couldn't seem to get the correct answer, but if I add in assert(p!=NULL); before the memset commands like seen in Fe203's answer, it does work. Also, if I did the memset commands before my constant commands, that would also produce the desired result. Do you know why it works this way? I thought you could just use memset just freely but it seems there is some directional use like before one thing or using assert statement.

Comment: @pew: I discovered a bug in my posted code. I have removed a `*` in all three lines containing `memset`. See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73396666/revisions) to see the changes. Does it work properly now?

Comment: @pew: Note that the line `char* valueArray[INITIAL_SIZE][101];` in your code is probably wrong, because you are declaring a (multidimensional) array of `INITIALSIZE * 101` pointers. This is probably not what you want. The line `char valueArray[INITIAL_SIZE][101];` will instead declare an array of `INITIAL_SIZE` `char` arrays of length `101` characters (i.e. you should remove the `*`).

Comment: Andreas removing the * in memset now works as I get zeros in all positions and not memory addresses. Also, I realized from Fe203 that I only needed a char 2D array to store strings for the values. I think my code is fundamentally good now in storage, now just needs some features. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

To initialise a region of memory (an instance of a struct either as a local variable or from the heap) where most elements are NULL (or false), simply use:

```
table t;
memset( &t, 0, sizeof t );
```

Then go on to initialise the few elements that are not NULL or 0 or false:

```
#include <assert.h>

void initTable( table* p ) {
        assert( p != NULL );

        memset( p, 0, sizeof *p );
        p->capacity = INITIAL_SIZE;
        p->loadFactor = LOAD_FACTOR; 
        p->collisionHandler = true;
}
```

Kudos for using "include guards" in the header file. More conventional would be using an UPPERCASE token, and perhaps even a suffix...

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
```

One further suggestion:

```
char* valueArray[INITIAL_SIZE][100 + 1];
```

makes it clear (to me) that the '\0' is being considered in this allocation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. What is the effect of assert (p!=NULL); in this situation?

Comment: Also, I am getting this error from your solution when initializing valueArray and trying to print it in gbd debugger (I expect print p->valueArray to print ({0x0 <repeats 101 times>},{0x0 <repeats 101 times>},{0x0 <repeats 101 times>},{0x0 <repeats 101 times>},{0x0 <repeats 101 times>}), but I get instead: {0x0 <repeats 101 times>}, {0xfffffffe <Address 0xfffffffe out of bounds>, 0x1 <Address 0x1 out of bounds>,
    0x260024 <Address 0x260024 out of bounds>, 0x775250 

and a bunch more weird stuff

Comment: @pew Q1: Look at the man page for `assert()`. Its purpose is minimal protection against trying to dereference a NULL pointer. It does its job when compiled with debugging enabled. Q2: I just noticed your `char* valueArray[ ] [ ]`... Do you really mean a 2D array of pointers? Or did you mean a 2D array of `char`... That '*' may be wrong and causing the messages you are seeing... Let me know...

Comment: I am trying to make a string array, so actually I suppose I would just need a char* array of the starting length, for example char* valueArray[INITIAL_SIZE], in order to have INITIAL_SIZE char pointers that can be expanded to strings?

Comment: @pew You probably want `char arr[ rows ][ length + 1 ];` then you can refer to 'arr[ i ]` as if it were a pointer. (`char *p = arr [ i ];`) What you just suggested cannot be 'expanded' unless you begin to use `malloc()` (or its equivalent.) It's worth thinking and experimenting with a tiny program (just one array) to learn how the different declarations work. Simplify the problem until you get the picture. :-)

Comment: @Fe203 I did what you suggested and tried it out and now the basic capabilities of my hashtable work after some modifications. Thank you very much